# p-value NaN when using goodfit() on binomial data

Tags: r

I am attempting to test the goodness of fit for a vector of count data to a binomial.  To do so I am using the `goodfit()` function in the `vcd` package.  When I run the function, however, it returns `NaN` for the p-value of the Chi-squared test.  In my setup, I have a vector of count data with 75 elements.

```
> library(vcd)
> counts
 [1] 32 35 44 35 41 33 42 49 36 41 42 45 38 43 36 35 40 40 43 34 39 31 40 39 36 37 37 37 32 48 41 32 37 36 49 37 41 36 34 37 41 32 36 36 30 33 33 42 39 36 36 29 31
[54] 41 36 39 40 37 39 39 31 39 37 40 33 41 34 46 35 41 44 38 44 34 42
> test.gof <- goodfit(counts, type="binomial", 
+                     par=list(size=length(counts), prob=0.5))
```

Everything works fine, but when I inspect the `goodfit()` object I get the following:

```
> summary(test.gof)

 Goodness-of-fit test for binomial distribution

                      X^2 df  P(> X^2)
Pearson               NaN 75       NaN
Likelihood Ratio 21.48322 19 0.3107244
Warning message:
In summary.goodfit(test.gof) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

I suspected it was a small sample size issue at first, but I also have a data set with 50 observations that does not return `NaN` for the p-value.  I have also tried to switch the method in `goodfit()` to ML with similar results.

Why would this function be producing `NaN` in this case?  Is there an alternative function to calculate GOF on count data?

Data used:

```
counts <- c(32, 35, 44, 35, 41, 33, 42, 49, 36, 41, 42, 45, 38, 43, 36, 
35, 40, 40, 43, 34, 39, 31, 40, 39, 36, 37, 37, 37, 32, 48, 41, 
32, 37, 36, 49, 37, 41, 36, 34, 37, 41, 32, 36, 36, 30, 33, 33, 
42, 39, 36, 36, 29, 31, 41, 36, 39, 40, 37, 39, 39, 31, 39, 37, 
40, 33, 41, 34, 46, 35, 41, 44, 38, 44, 34, 42)
```